# No space left on device, cardano-db-sync to blame?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

I'm getting errors when starting up my producer suggesting I'm out of storage. It looks like db/immutable is the culprit taking almost 100g of space. I'm not super familiar with what this db is or what writes to it.

Is this possibly cardano-db-sync which I'm running by mistake? Is this unneeded for my producer and is it possible to safely delete these files and remove whatever process is writing them?

Answer (score 2):

> It looks like db/immutable is the culprit taking almost 100g of spac

Yes, that is part of the `cardano-node`'s on disk storage. I have just checked mine (on Linux) and the disk space used is only 72G. Looks like you may have some extra files in there taking up space.

> Is this possibly cardano-db-sync which I'm running by mistake?

Very unlikely. Look at the logs. If its `db-sync` it will very clearly say so. Likewise with the node.

Answer (score -1):

db/immutable looks like the db for the Cardano node (please make sure, check full path). If so, it is safe to, stop the node, and then delete the contents of the db directory, but you will need to wait for a full sync after starting it again (which will take some time and around 72G of space once complete), or you could copy the directory from another node (i.e. one relay), and then start the node to finish sync, which will save you some time.

About checking for other services running, please check i.e. :

```
systemctl | grep running
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled 
ps aux
```

If you think another process is writing to the directory, you could gather extra information using iotop or fatrace, i.e.:

```
sudo apt-get install fatrace
sudo fatrace | grep immutable
```

Cheers,
Josep